# Finding: $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin (ax)|^c - |\sin(bx)|^c}{x} \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that for $a,b,c>0$ $$\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin 
>  (ax)|^c- |\sin(bx)|^c}{x} \, dx = \log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \frac{\Gamma(1+c)}{2^c\Gamma^2\left(1+\frac c2\right)}.$$

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is not correct - I checked numerically for $c=\frac{1}{2}; a=2; b=1$. Using the Frullani' integral for a periodic function, and defining $\,0<c<1; \,\,a,b>0$, the correct answer is 
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin 
 (ax)|^c- |\sin(bx)|^c}{x} \, dx = \log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \frac{\Gamma\left(c+1\right)}{2^c\,\Gamma^2\left(1+\frac c2\right)} $$
what gives $0.528...$ for both sides at $c=\frac{1}{2}; a=2; b=1$

Comment: Unfortunately for your strategy, $\Im e^{iacx}=\sin(acx)\not\equiv|\sin(ax)|^c$.

Comment: Also, very useful more general relation
$$\int_0^\pi e^{ibx}\sin^{a-1}x~dx=\frac{\pi e^{i\pi b/2}}{2^{a-1}a\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2},\frac{a-b+1}{2}\right)}$$
A comprehensive proof may be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419834/integrals-related-to-the-reciprocal-beta-function?noredirect=1

Comment: Also, could be useful https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.35.10.612

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks for taking your time! The second link is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "periodic Frullani" approach (that I use in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4437259)): for any $\tau$-periodic function $f$ such that the integral $\int_0^\tau\big(f(x)/x\big)\,dx$ exists (in Lebesgue's sense), and any $a,b>0$, we have $$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}\,dx=\frac1\tau\log\frac{a}{b}\int_0^\tau f(x)\,dx.$$ Take $f(x)=|\sin x|^c$ (and $\tau=\pi$) and use $\int_0^\pi(\sin x)^c\,dx=\mathrm{B}\big(1/2,(c+1)/2\big)$.

Comment: I think you are missing the  term near $0$: $\log(a/b)\Big(\bar{f}-f(0+)\Big)$ where $\bar{f}=\frac1\tau\int^\tau_0f$

Comment: No need for $\int^1_0\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$ as you can see in the proof that posted. The possible singularity at $0$ is controlled by the difference $f(ax)-f(bx)$ with the additional conditions I laid down.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to elaborate on my comment to @matamorphy's answer.

> Assume $f$ is bounded, $T$-periodic, integrable in $[0,T]$, and that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}f(t)=f_0$ exists.
> For any $0<a<b$,
> \begin{align}
> \int^\infty_0\frac{f(at) - f(bt)}{t}\,dt=\log(a/b)\Big(\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f(t)\,dt - f_0\Big)
> \end{align}
> where the integral on the left-hand-side is considered as improper Riemann integral.

Here is a sketch of the proof:
\begin{align}
\int^A_\varepsilon\frac{f(at)}{t}\,dt-\int^A_\varepsilon\frac{f(bt)}{t}\,dt&=\int^{aA}_{a\varepsilon} \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt-\int^{bA}_{b\varepsilon} \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\int^{b\varepsilon}_{a\varepsilon}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt-\int^{Ab}_{Aa}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\int^b_a\frac{f(\varepsilon t)}{t}\,dt-\int^a_b\frac{f(At)}{t}\,dt
\end{align}

The right continuity of $f$ at $0$ implies that
\begin{align}\int^b_a\frac{f(\varepsilon t)}{t}\,dt&\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}f_0\log(b/a)
\end{align}
[Fejer's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) implies that
\begin{align}\int^b_a\frac{f(A t)}{t}\,dt&\xrightarrow{A\rightarrow\infty}\log(b/a)\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f(t)\,dt
\end{align}
Putting things together yields Frullani's integral formula for periodic functions:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{f(at) - f(bt)}{t}\,dt=\log(a/b)\Big(\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f(t)\,dt - f_0\Big)
\end{align}